# Terminal - command not found

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, command

I'm trying to learn to write shell scripts and use the Terminal.

In Users/user/Development/linux I've got a script called sysinfo_page.

So I'm in the linux folder in the terminal and I can see the sysinfo_page when I type the ls command.

However, when I enter the following command:

```
sysinfo_page > sysinfo_page.html
```

I receive the following message:

> -bash: sysinfo_page: command not found

How do I resolve this?

Comment: What do you want to do? If you want to see the file, you can `cat sysinfo_page` or `more sysinfo_page`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run a script file form the current directory, you have to write `./` before your script name:

```
./script.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Your command may not be an executable file. Try this:

```
chmod +x sysinfo_page
./sysinfo_page > sysinfo_page.html
```

The first line will set the eXecutable flag on the file, the second will run it from the current dir. Note that if you want to run a file in the current directory and that dir is not included in your `PATH`, you need to prepend `./` or else the shell won't find it.